# Windows cannot find any networks after

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Periodically (like every week) I will suddenly lose connection from my network. Usually everything will run fine but when this happens Windows displays the red X over the wireless icon and it will say "No connections are available." My other devices can connect fine to my wireless network and have no connection disruption.

- The troubleshooter does not bring up anything
- Disabling the Wireless Network adapater and reenabling did not work
- Both restarting the `Network Connections` service and the `Network List Service` using `net start ___` and `net stop ___` do not help the situation
- Restarting the computer fixes it (it's just an annoyance due to the length of the startup for this computer)

Any thoughts on other fixes I can try to jolt the service back to life?

Comment: Try resetting the ip stack. Run the following commands in a cmd shell: `netsh int ip reset`, then `netsh winsock reset` and finally `netsh advfirewall reset`

Comment: @DavidPostill The first two say I need to restart in order to complete this action although they both say they were successful. No change to the network lack of network discovery though.

Comment: So have you restarted as requested?

Comment: I mean, that will fix the problem (non-permanently) regardless of if I had reset the ip stack or not. If you were aiming for a permanent fix I'll restart and report back if it happens again in the future

Comment: It depends on what is causing the problem. It may or may not be a permanent fix. It may not fix it at all (but it a good troubleshooting step).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like the restart fixes it (and the service restart doesn't) because it resets your actual WiFi adapter hardware.  Going with that theory tells me the WiFi adapter's hardware is faulty.

Replace the WiFi adapter with a known-good adapter, and test again.

Comment: It isn't restarting my wireless adapter? When my computer disconnects all my other devices are still connected so I believe it's just this one computer.

Comment: @Coburn That's what I'm talking about, the wireless adapter in your computer (the one that's giving you troubles). :)

Comment: Oh, my bad, read that as just WiFi. Honestly, this possibility is not that unlikely.

Comment: Definitely sounds like WiFi adapter on its way out.  Pretty common unfortunately.  My theory is that in many laptop designs the WiFi adapter doesn't get cooled properly thus shortening its life.  A possible workaround is to disable the onboard WiFi adapter (via BIOS setup) and use an inexpensive USB dongle WiFi adapter instead.  Or else replace the onboard one but that can be a right pain especially if your laptop has a BIOS hardware white-list which may restrict what you can put in there.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a laptop you are working with, try disabling Wifi then re-enable (often a physical switch on the laptop meant for airplane mode)  This will power down and restart the Wifi hardware

Comment: Nope, it's a desktop, but disabling the device and reenabling (in the wireless adapter settings did not fix the problem)

Comment: OK a longshot suggestion then, have you tried physically unplugging the network cable and then reconnecting it?

Comment: @JimSmith Wireless! Nothing to unplug :-p